# Is a derivative work necessarily written in same language as the one it derives from?

Tags: derivative-works

For example, a C repository built upon the ***ideas*** from a (say) JavaScript project - is it a derivative work based on the latter?

To clear things up little bit, i'd give a more detailed example;
Imagine an open source compiler written in JavaScript implements in its code base a high quality code optimization algorithm its authors have discover'd; my question is, can other works, no matter open source or not, incorporate the algorithms in their own code (which might not have been written in the same language as the code whose ideas it is using) and still not be consider'd "derivatives" (partially at least) of the oiginal work?

Comment: A project that's ported to another language is still derived from the original project.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I think you're wrong. Google duplicated java *without changing the same language* and it's unclear wether or not they infringed copyright. Under the arguments used in that court case, I think if Google had done just a few things differently (like changing the language) then they would have had a clear victory and been ruled as not infringing Oracle's copyright.

Comment: The question in the title can be easily answered: No. Take any GPL-library that is called from another than its own programing language (and don't subscribe to the 'linking is irrelevant' pov). The question in the body is a different one, in my opinion - a C project can be based on the ideas of another C project as well. OP, which question would you really like to be answered?

Comment: @AbhiBeckert My understanding is that Google duplicate the Java *API*, which is a very different matter from porting an algorithm or procedure.

Comment: @curiousdannii yep, the question was rewritten after my comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does copyrighted code protect intellectual property rights on novel algorithms it implements?](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1870/does-copyrighted-code-protect-intellectual-property-rights-on-novel-algorithms-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algorthms and ideas are not elligible for copyright.

As long as it hasn't been patented you can create your own implementation without worrying about copyright (just make sure you copy the algorithm not the code).

If you're not sure, contact a lawyer.

Comment: thanks for the response; please correct anything i've gotten wrong, does it mean people can derive their work from another work, doing so without causing their work to become a "derivative work" (copyright-wise?  )

Comment: @icefapper many things are not eligible for copyright and for those things, it is impossible to infringe on copyright in any way (including derivative works). if you're worried you should ask a lawyer, I haven't seen enough details about your specific case to give you a bulletproof answer and I'm not a lawyer anyway.

Comment: It really depends on whether you used the ideas, or if you "translated the code." The latter would certainly be considered a derivative work.